# multiple block on the same height?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

Just a quick question , in the blockchain api quoting from the documentation it says:

```
get_block_height

Get an **array** of blocks at the specified height. Returns an array of Block objects.

Params:

height : int - block height
```

why will it be an array? because i thought the blocks that are not on the main branch will be disregarded thus one height will only be one block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockchain.com is not a blockchain node, it is an explorer. They have no constraint on following the same rules as a Bitcoin Core node, and can keep orphaned and forked blocks available if they wish to, and return all blocks they know of for a block height if they wish to.

In the main Bitcoin chain, things are as you say - Only a single block may survive at a given block height. If multiple blocks are mined for a given block height, the chain with the most amount of work done (essentially the block with the longest chain of descendant blocks) will be kept, and the other will be orphaned.